# SPQUERY returns null value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, caml-query, query, spquery

Hi im using sp query to retrieve the items and using projectproperty.Title  to get the web name dynamically ,but I got empty value in this data table.

```
              q.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/>" + "<FieldRef Name='Modified'/>";
                    q.ViewFields += "<ProjectProperty Name=\"Title\" />";
                    q.ViewFields += "<ListProperty Name=\"Title\" />";

                   q.Query="<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>";

                   q.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='ProjectProperty.Title' /><Value Type='Text'>Test1</Value></Contains></Where>";
  DataTable results = spWeb.GetSiteData(q);
```

if I removed projectproperty.title in my query its working fine.any suggestion.?

Answer (score 0):

according to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/db02a7d6-c3c9-48ad-8408-04640c6e1a4c/using-projectproperty-in-caml-where-clause) you cannot filter based on projectproperty

I must add that I haven't tried it myself, though.